# Does this piecewise sum converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to study the convergence of the piecewise sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ where
$$ 
 a_n =
\begin{cases}
(1+\frac{1}{43n})^{n^{43}},  & n=3p, p \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \\
7*5^n & n=3p+1, p \in \mathbb{N} \\
33 n, & n=3p+2, p \in \mathbb{N} \\
(\frac18)^n & n = 3p+3, p \in \mathbb{N}  
\end{cases}
$$

It is obvious by the divergence test that all cases diverge, except $(\frac18)^n $ which converges as a geometric sum.

But to me it is not obvious, what $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does.

**Note:** My intuition tells me that since there is **at least one case** where the sum goes to infinity (diverges) then no matter what the other cases do, the sum is going to diverge ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n= +\infty$). But I cannot prove it.

So, does the sum converge or diverge and why?

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is well-defined. But if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to0$.

Comment: It diverges! It suffices to check that the general term does not tend to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

In order to converge to $L$, after some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, you must have $|a_n - L|$ get as small as needed for all $a_{N+1}, a_{N+2}, \ldots$ So if you have a diverging subsequence, a sequence cannot converge.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, since $a_n > 0$, we can observe that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \ge \sum_{p=1}^\infty a_{(3p+2)}=\sum_{p=1}^\infty 33p =\infty$$